# why am I getting this 'the referenced script on this Behavior is missing!' error in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple FPS movement script in Unity. I made a player called 'player' with a capsule collider, a rigidbody, and a camera. Everything worked fine until I finished writing the code for the WASD movement, then it said that my referenced script was missing. The script was exactly where it was before and hadn't been renamed. I deleted everything and started over, and got the same error.

the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody player;
    public float m_speed, rotatespeed;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            player.velocity = transform.forward * m_speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            player.velocity = -transform.forward * m_speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            player.velocity = -transform.right * m_speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            player.velocity = transform.right * m_speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

    }  

}
```

Comment: One Recommendation is you always use Normal Uppercase in the first letter and subsequent lower case. Also why don't you try removing it and then reading it like right click remove component and then drag the script form the assets to the inspector while object is selected again

Comment: Can you also add a picture of the inspector window of the player object? Sometimes Unity mixes things up there if you rename/move scripts...

Comment: Related to Lae’s point: if you move or rename Unity asset files like scripts be sure to also move or rename the associated .meta file.

Comment: I figured it out, turns out that the 'movement' that was referred to in the script was actually named 'playerMovement'.

Answer (score 0):

The filename **must** match the class name e.g.

`Something.cs` -> `public class Something : MonoBehaviour`

If you rename your file, Unity won't update the class name inside the file. This is also case sensitive if I am not mistaken